# Prove $f\colon X/{\sim} \to Y \text{ is continuous} \iff \pi\circ f\colon X \to Y \text{ is continuous}$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I need to show that $$f\colon X/{\sim} \to Y \text{ is continuous} \iff \pi\circ f\colon X \to Y \text{ is continuous}$$

where $X/{\sim}$ is a quotient topology and $\pi$ is the quotient map.

I understand the proof for  $$f\colon X/{\sim} \to Y \text{ is continuous} \iff f\circ \pi\colon X \to Y \text{ is continuous}$$ which is quite simple. But I can't see how to break this one down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general hint: by definition of the quotient topology, the projection $\pi$ is continuous. Question: is the composition of continuous functions a continuous function?

In your case I do not agree with notation, as $\pi$ is a quotient map, i.e.
$\pi: X\rightarrow X\setminus\sim$ or $\pi: Y\rightarrow Y\setminus\sim$ . In either the first or second case, I can not compose $\pi$ with $f: X\setminus\sim\rightarrow Y$ and arrive at the map $\pi\circ f: X\rightarrow Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was considering this but it seemed a little  too simple :P